# (g)awk next file on partially blank line

Tags: awk, gawk

### The Problem

I just need to combine a whole bunch of files and strip out the header (line 1) from the 1st file.

### The Data

Here are the last three lines (with line 1: header) from three of these files:

```
"START_DATE","END_DATE","UNITS","COST","COST_CURRENCY","AMOUNT"
"20170101","20170131","1","5.49","EUR","5.49"
"20170101","20170131","1","4.27","EUR","4.27"
"","","","","9.76",""

"START_DATE","END_DATE","UNITS","COST","COST_CURRENCY","AMOUNT"
"20170201","20170228","1","5.49","EUR","5.49"
"20170201","20170228","1","4.88","EUR","4.88"
"20170201","20170228","1","0.61","EUR","0.61"
"20170201","20170228","1","0.61","EUR","0.61"
"","","","","11.59",""

START_DATE","END_DATE","UNITS","COST","COST_CURRENCY","AMOUNT"
"20170301","20170331","1","4.88","EUR","4.88"
"20170301","20170331","1","4.27","EUR","4.27"
"","","","","9.15",""
```

### Problem (Continued)

As you can see, the last line has a number (it's a column total) in column 5. Of course, I don't want that last line. But it's (obviously) on a different line number in each file.

(G)awk is clearly the solution, but I don't know (g)awk.

### What I've Tried

I've tried a number of combinations of things, but I guess the one that I'm most surprised does *not* work is:

```
gawk '
  { if (!$1 ) nextfile }
  NR == 1 {$0 = "Filename" "StartDate" OFS $0; print} 
  FNR > 1 {$0 =  FILENAME StartDate OFS $0; print}
' OFS=',' */*.csv > ../path/file.csv
```

### Expected Output (by request)

```
"START_DATE","END_DATE","UNITS","COST","COST_CURRENCY","AMOUNT
20170101","20170131","1","5.49","EUR","5.49
20170101","20170131","1","4.27","EUR","4.27
20170201","20170228","1","5.49","EUR","5.49
20170201","20170228","1","4.88","EUR","4.88
20170201","20170228","1","0.61","EUR","0.61
20170201","20170228","1","0.61","EUR","0.61
20170301","20170331","1","4.88","EUR","4.88
20170301","20170331","1","4.27","EUR","4.27"
```

And, of course, I've tried searching both Google and SO. Most of the answers I see require much more awk knowledge than I have, just to understand them. (I'm not a data wrangler, but I have a data wrangling task.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: post the final expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do...

```
awk 'NR==1; FNR==1{next} FNR>2{print p} {p=$0}' file{1..3}
```

print first header, skip other headers and last lines.

Comment: That worked!! Even better: I understand *why* it worked! Thanks @karakfa (and everyone else, too, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
 awk -F"," 'NR==1{header=$0; print $0} $0!=header && $1!=""{print $0}' */*.csv > ../path/file.csv\
```

Here awk will:

1. Split the records by comma `-F","`
2. If this is the first record awk encounters, it sets variable `header` to the entire contents of the line and then prints the header `NR==1{header=$0; print $0}`
3. If the contents of the current line are not a header and the first field isn't empty (indicating a "total" line), then print the line `$0!=header && $1!=""{print $0}'`

---

As mentioned in my comment below, if the first field of your records always begin with an 8 digit date, then you could simplify (this is less generic than the code above):

```
 awk -F"," 'NR == 1 || $1 ~ /"[0-9]{8}"/ {print $0} /*.csv > outfile.csv
```

Essentially that says if this is the first record to process then print it (it's a header) OR `||` if the first field is an 8 digit number surrounded by double quotes then print it.

Comment: This gets me really close. But it's keeping the header rows for all files. Thanks! I will try to mess with your line, maybe I'll stumble on solving it from there!

UPDATE: I tried adding `FNR > 1 {print $0}`, but that put those last lines back in!

Comment: Perhaps then your headers in each file differ a bit. You could change that second block's condition to be: `$1!="START_DATE" && $1!=""{...` If that works for your needs, then just remove the bit in the first block that sets the `header` variable since that is unnecessary. You could also use a condition that checks for a numeric first field of length 8 (a date) in between double quotes and prints for that second block like:  `awk -F"," 'NR==1{print $0} $1~/"[0-9]{8}"/{print $0}` /*.csv > outfile.csv` That's less generic, but it might be easier over all.

Answer (score 1):

Another **awk** approach:-

```
awk -F, '
        NR == 1 {
                header = $0
                print
                next
        }
        FNR > 1 && $1 != "\"\""
' *.csv
```

Comment: thanks! I actually understand what this one does, so I tried it first. But it doesn't kick out the last line for some reason. I still get the lines with the column total.